# 4-4-5 DAX Calendar with Leap Years

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Did any of you manage to create a 4-4-5 calendar based on Dax in Power BI without any Excel spreadsheet?
For us, each fiscal year begins on the first Monday of the year and then takes place on a 4-4-5 week basis. 
What is the approach now to extend to a leap year in which the last quarter turns to 4-4-6?

Comment: why you do not want to load any Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Is this the only chance to include the 4-4-6 period?

Comment: There are always infinite ways to complete the same task, however, some might be more complex or over-engineered than other. Therefore, I was asking you the reason why you excluded a priori a simple approach.

Comment: Why do you need to extend the last qtr to be 4-4-6 in a leap year? 4-4-5 doesn't split the year evenly, you have 1 day remaining in a 'normal' year so wouldn't you just treat the extra day in a leap year the same?

Comment: The 4-4-5 approach contains just 364 days. You need to include a 4-4-6 approach after a few years.